# No visible @interface 'PhotosTableViewController' declares the selector 'viewWithImageName'

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoapods

I am learning to integrate CocoaPods into my project.

I have downloaded and installed the MCSwipeTableView into my project.

I have been stuck on this for hours and read the other related answers to this question.

This is the line where the "No visible @interface" error happens:

```
UIView *checkView = [self viewWithImageName:@"check"];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#import "PhotosTableViewController.h"
#import "MCSwipeTableViewCell.h"

@interface PhotosTableViewController () <MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {

    NSMutableArray *photos;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger nbItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCSwipeTableViewCell *cellToDelete;

@end

@implementation PhotosTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Photos";

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    // create array
    photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    Photo *pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
    pic.names = @"Lemon Cover";
    pic.fileName = @"lemon cover";
    pic.notes = @"This is the ebook title picture of my original eBook that was never published due to various reasons.";

    [photos addObject:pic];

    pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
    pic.names = @"Off Camera Celebrity";
    pic.fileName = @"offcameralogo4";
    pic.notes = @"My first idea that I really pursued on my own. It started as one thing and quickly led to much more.";
    [photos addObject:pic];

    pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
    pic.names = @"Soup Recipe Book";
    pic.fileName = @"Soup Ebook Cover";
    pic.notes = @"This was the best non-published ebook I had that Amazon shut down again.";
    [photos addObject:pic];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return photos.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MCSwipeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // iOS 7 separator
        if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (void)configureCell:(MCSwipeTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Configuring the views and colors.
    UIView *checkView = [self viewWithImageName:@"check"];
    UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0 / 255.0 green:213.0 / 255.0 blue:80.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIView *crossView = [self viewWithImageName:@"cross"];
    UIColor *redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:232.0 / 255.0 green:61.0 / 255.0 blue:14.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIView *clockView = [self viewWithImageName:@"clock"];
    UIColor *yellowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254.0 / 255.0 green:217.0 / 255.0 blue:56.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIView *listView = [self viewWithImageName:@"list"];
    UIColor *brownColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:206.0 / 255.0 green:149.0 / 255.0 blue:98.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];

    // Setting the default inactive state color to the tableView background color.
    [cell setDefaultColor:self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor];

    // Configure the cell...
    Photo *current = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [current names];

    // Adding gestures per state basis.
    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:checkView color:greenColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState1 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Checkmark\" cell");
    }];

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:crossView color:redColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState2 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Cross\" cell");
    }];

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:clockView color:yellowColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState3 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"Clock\" cell");
    }];

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:listView color:brownColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState4 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        NSLog(@"Did swipe \"List\" cell");
    }];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
//- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
//{
//    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
//    DisplaysViewController *pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
//    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
//    // What's the selected cell?
//    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
//    Photo *c = photos [path.row];
//    [pvc setCurrentPhoto:c];
//    
//}


@end
```

Comment: Do you think that `PhotosTableViewController` **does** have a `viewWithImageName` method?  I don't see one declared/defined.

Comment: The error message is vey explicit -- you haven't implemented that method in your controller. If you look at the demo project that the author of the MCSwipeTableViewCell has provided, you will see that he does have that method defined in his table view controller.

Answer (score 4):

First off, it's a warning not an error. But it will probably be an error when your app executes that line of code.

The object `self` does not have a method `viewWithImageName`. You need to add that method to the class.

A quick google search found this method which some people use on GitHub. Just add it to your class:

```
- (UIView *)viewWithImageName:(NSString *)imageName {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    return imageView;
}
```

https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell/blob/master/MCSwipe%20Demo/MCSwipe%20Demo/MCTableViewController.m

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I know it's a rookie mishap but man did I spend a long time doing the wrong thing trying to make this work